# vscode not recognizing types from installed github repo

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

- I have a shared repo, let's call it **Shared**.
- I have a consumer repo, let's call it **Consumer**.

In the **Shared** repo I define some typings and code that I want to use in **Consumer**.

In the **Shared** repo I have files like this:

```
<Shared repo>/
├─ types/
│  ├─ User.ts
├─ models/
   ├─ UserModel.ts
```

And let's say the User.ts file looks as simple as follows:

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
}
```

I do not want to npm publish **Shared** repo as an npm module.

I simply install it from the GitHub URL in my **Consumer** repo, for example

```
npm install https://github.com/user/shared#main
```

so in my **Consumer** package.json I will see

```
dependencies: {
  ...
  "shared": "github:user/shared#main"
  ...
}
```

But my vscode is not suggesting imports from the **Shared** repo when I try to use *User* type. How can I get vscode to recognize these types?

Comment: Does your "shared" repo follow [the instructions for publishing types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)?

Comment: @user Thanks for pointing that out. It does not. Will try to update and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/user) for pointing out that I should follow [the instructions for publishing types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

Step by step:

1. I used `src` folder for my development code, `build` folder for built code using [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)
2. `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */
  "compilerOptions": {

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "types": ["node"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,

    /* JavaScript Support */
    "allowJs": true,

    /* Emit */
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

3. In `package.json` there need to be following values defined:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "types": "build/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

4. I used [ctix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ctix) module for automatically creating index file with exports.

To root level of project, added `.ctic` file with content:

```
  // common configuration
  // tsconfig.json path: you must pass path with filename, like this "./tsconfig.json"
  "project": "./tsconfig.json",

  // create, single command configuration
  // add ctix comment at first line of creted index.ts file, that remark created from ctix
  "useSemicolon": true,

  // timestamp write on ctix comment right-side, only works in useComment option set true
  "useTimestamp": false,
  
  // add ctix comment at first line of creted index.ts file, that remark created from ctix
  "useComment": true,

  // quote mark " or '
  "quote": "'",

  // overwrite index.ts file also index.ts file already exist that create backup file
  "overwrite": true,

  // keep file extension in export statement path
  "keepFileExt": false,
  
  // only create command configuration
  // If set true this option, skip empty directory
  "skipEmptyDir": true,

  // only single command configuration
  // Output directory. It works only single mode.
  "output": "./src",

  // Use rootDir or rootDirs configuration in tsconfig.json.
  "useRootDir": false,

  // only remove command configuration
  // remove with backup file
  "includeBackup": true
}
```

In `package.json` add a script:

```
{
   ...
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "build": "ctix single && npm run clean && tsc --build",
     "clean": "rm -fr build",
     ...
   }
  ...
}
```

5. Now to "publish" changes, I need to run
   `npm run build`
   After that git commit and push your code **including build folder**